Adjusting Keras OCR Model Settings to Detect and Recognize Floating-Point Numbers
I am using the Keras OCR library for optical character recognition and I'm encountering an issue with recognizing floating-point numbers, specifically numbers with decimal points. Currently, the OCR model is detecting numbers like "700.25" as "70025", merging the digits instead of recognizing the decimal point.
Here's an example of what I've tried:
Custom Recognizer:
I have created a custom Recognizer with an adjusted alphabet to include the "." (dot) character:
Despite this adjustment, the OCR still does not reliably recognize floating-point numbers.
`
import keras_ocr
def detect_and_print_numbers(image_path):
# Create a custom Recognizer with adjusted alphabet to include "."
recognizer = keras_ocr.recognition.Recognizer(alphabet="0123456789.")

# Create the pipeline with the custom Recognizer
pipeline = keras_ocr.pipeline.Pipeline(recognizer=recognizer)

# Recognize text in the image
prediction_groups = pipeline.recognize([image_path])

recognized_numbers = []

# Iterate through predictions and print recognized text
for predictions in prediction_groups:
    for prediction in predictions:
        text = ''.join(prediction[0])  # Join predicted characters into a string
        recognized_numbers.append(text)

return recognized_numbers

Example usage
image_path = '/path/to/your/image.jpg'
recognized_numbers = detect_and_print_numbers(image_path)

# Print recognized numbers
for number in recognized_numbers:
    print(f"Recognized Text: {number}")

`
Result is
('70025', array([[..., instead of "700.25
OCR Model Settings:
According to the Keras OCR documentation, there are parameters like text_threshold and link_threshold that can be adjusted to potentially improve the detection of finer details such as decimal points. However, I'm unsure of the exact settings that would optimize the OCR for this specific task.
Question:
How can I adjust the Keras OCR model settings effectively to ensure accurate detection and recognition of decimal points in floating-point numbers? Are there specific parameters or techniques within the Pipeline, Detector, or Recognizer classes that I should focus on?
Any insights or examples on configuring these settings to handle decimal points correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The Keras-OCR documentation mentions text_threshold and link_threshold parameters in the Detector class, which might help with decimal point detection, but it does not provide specific guidance.
The Recognizer class allows specifying an alphabet parameter, potentially including the decimal point character. However, there are no examples or discussions on improving floating-point number recognition with this feature.
Based on available information, the Keras-OCR library lacks built-in functionality for detecting and recognizing decimal points in floating-point numbers.
